# Google sign in sometimes not rendering in React app

Tags: reactjs, google-signin

I am following [this article](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/tools/configurator) to set up Google in my app, and I created the HTML code and pasted it into my Login component, but **sometimes** (for example I land on http://localhost:3000/login, no button, I refresh a few times, boom, it's there ), the button is not rendering on the page. I can't see any error in the console related to it. Below you will the full Login component. Testing on http://localhost:3000/ and is in Authorized JavaScript origins

Login component:

```
import { useState, useContext } from "react";
import AuthContext from "../utils/AuthContext";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  Container,
  Form,
  Button,
  Card,
  FormGroup,
  FormControl,
  Row,
  Col,
} from "react-bootstrap";
import Image from 'react-bootstrap/Image';

function Register() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [password2, setPassword2] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const { registerUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    const isRegistered = await registerUser(username, password, password2, email);
    
    if (isRegistered) {
      navigate("/login", { state: { username } });
    }
  };
  

  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#fff", minHeight: "100vh", color: "#000", display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
      <a href="https://doctrina.ai" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
    <Image className="logo mt-5 mb-5" loading="lazy" responsive src="https://i.ibb.co/C7ykCPj/logo-white.png" />
</a>
      </div>
      <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <Container>
          <Row className="justify-content-md-center pt-3">
            <Col md={6}>
              <Card>
                <Card.Body>
                  <h1 className="text-center mb-3">Create free account</h1>
                  <h6 className="text-center mb-3">Join over 300000 students already using Doctrina and enjoy free AI features</h6>
                  <div id="g_id_onload"
     data-client_id="working client id"
     data-context="signup"
     data-ux_mode="popup"
     data-login_uri="http://localhost:3000/register"
     data-auto_select="true"
     data-itp_support="true">
</div>

<div className="g_id_signin"
     data-type="standard"
     data-shape="rectangular"
     data-theme="outline"
     data-text="signin_with"
     data-size="large"
     data-logo_alignment="left">
</div>
                  <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <FormGroup controlId="formBasicEmail" className="mt-5 register-form">
                      <FormControl
                        type="text"
                        id="email"
                        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                        placeholder="Enter your email"
                        required
                        style={{ width: "100%", minWidth: "100% !important" }}
                      />
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup controlId="formBasicUsername" className="mt-5">
                      <FormControl
                        type="text"
                        id="username"
                        onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
                        placeholder="Enter your username"
                        required
                        style={{ width: "100%", minWidth: "100% !important" }}
                      />
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup controlId="formBasicPassword" className="mt-5">
                      <FormControl
                        type="password"
                        id="password"
                        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                        placeholder="Enter your password"
                        required
                        style={{ width: "100%", minWidth: "100% !important" }}
                      />
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup
                      controlId="formBasicConfirmPassword"
                      className="mt-5"
                    >
                      <FormControl
                        type="password"
                        id="confirm-password"
                        onChange={(e) => setPassword2(e.target.value)}
                        placeholder="Confirm your password"
                        required
                        style={{ width: "100%", minWidth: "100% !important" }}
                      />
                      {password2 !== password && (
                        <p style={{ color: "red", marginTop: "0.5rem" }}>
                          Passwords do not match
                        </p>
                      )}
                    </FormGroup>
                    <Button
                      variant="primary"
                      type="submit"
                      className="w-50 mt-5 register-button"
                    >
                      Sign Up
                    </Button>
                    <p className="pt-3 already-account">Already have an account? <a className="primary" href="https://app.doctrina.ai/login">Log in</a></p>
                  </Form>
                </Card.Body>
              </Card>
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <ul className="list-unstyled text-center">
          <li className="pt-1">
            <a href="https://doctrina.ai/privacy.html" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Privacy policy</a>
          </li>
          <li className="pt-3">
            <a href="https://doctrina.ai/terms.html" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        </Container>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Register;
```

I have added `<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async></script>` in the <`head>` (tried both on top and bottom) of my index.html

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Can you see any request failing / getting cancelled in network tab?

Comment: nothing in the network, all good 200 :/